# how to write a trigger that forces a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, foreign-keys

I have a table name Service(product, loca, from_agent, to_agent).

product reference Product(pno)

from_agent references Customer(cno) U Driver(drno) U Airline(Ano)

to_agent references Customer(cno) U Driver(drno) U Airline(ano)

cno = Customer Number which is another table name "Customer"which has other details such as name, address etc

drno = Driver Number which is another table name "Driver" which has other details such as name, address etc

ano = Airline Number which is another table name "Airline"which has other details such as depport, depttime,arrtime etc..

would like to write a trigger that will force, the foreign key in the product table to be checked before any changes are made. Assuming local mapping transparency

Please help, I'm just learning about triggers and distribution database

Comment: Why use triggers for this and not just something obvious, like [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)?

Comment: @eggyal - I think that is what he has in mind.

Comment: cause i have a fragmented tables and i wanted to check the primary key on the other tables, that the cno in the Customer table exist, drno in the driver table exist, and ano actually exist in the airline table, if a user is trying to change any of the other fields,a trigger should be trigged to alert the user. i hope u got what i mean

Comment: Depending on the storage engine you use, you will have available or not foreign keys. I recommend you read the following article for a brief introduction [Enforcing Foreign Keys Programmatically in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Do we speak about FOREIGN KEY *** ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT?

Comment: @JamesBond: That is exactly what foreign key constraints will do.

Comment: @GrigoryKornilov: yes, that what i wanted to trigger to do.  @ eggyal: im just trying to read through the article which has being mentioned in one of the comments posted about, my problem is the syntax, how to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine a database for a shop: Items, Products, Brands (For exemple: "Yellow Peugeot bicycle with stripes", referenced as an item of "Peugeot bicycle", as a brand of "Peugeot".

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brands` (
`brandId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`brandName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`brandId`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `itemId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `generalProductId` int(11) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
   `productId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `productName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   `productBrand` int(11) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (`productId`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

 ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY(productBrand) REFERENCES brands(brandId) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE     CASCADE;
 ALTER TABLE items ADD FOREIGN KEY(itemBrand) REFERENCES product(productBrand) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

So here, you have a foreign key constraint, which makes Items inherit the brand specified in Product, which inherits itself from Brands. In this case, if you modify Name for a special BrandId, child tables will have the akncowledge of that. ON DELETE RESTRICT means that you cannot break the chain and database will not allow you to delete an entry that is referenced elsewhere :)